# SharpZipLib issues with WinZip version file

Tags: c#, unzip, sharpziplib

Hi i'm triying to uncompress a zip file with the library SharpZipLib v1.2.0 but i can't make it works.
The file that i try to uncompress was made with WinZip 9.0 and have password protection

I use this code for try to uncompress file but the throw me a exception with the message:

> ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipException: 'The library does not support the zip version required to extract this entry'

```
    public static Dictionary<string, MemoryStream> ExtractZipContent(MemoryStream m, string password)
    {
        Dictionary<string, MemoryStream> files = new Dictionary<string, MemoryStream>();
        ZipFile file = null;
        try
        {
            file = new ZipFile(m);
            file.UseZip64 = UseZip64.On;
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
            {
                // AES encrypted entries are handled automatically
                file.Password = password;
            }

            foreach (ZipEntry zipEntry in file)
            {
                if (!zipEntry.IsFile)
                {
                    // Ignore directories
                    continue;
                }

                String entryFileName = zipEntry.Name;
                // to remove the folder from the entry:- entryFileName = Path.GetFileName(entryFileName);
                // Optionally match entrynames against a selection list here to skip as desired.
                // The unpacked length is available in the zipEntry.Size property.

                // 4K is optimum
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
                Stream zipStream = file.GetInputStream(zipEntry);

                // Manipulate the output filename here as desired.
                //String fullZipToPath = Path.Combine(OutputFolder, entryFileName);
                //string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(fullZipToPath);

                //if (directoryName.Length > 0)
                //{
                //    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
                //}

                // Unzip file in buffered chunks. This is just as fast as unpacking to a buffer the full size
                // of the file, but does not waste memory.
                // The "using" will close the stream even if an exception occurs.
                //using (FileStream streamWriter = File.Create(fullZipToPath))
                //{

                MemoryStream s = new MemoryStream();
                StreamUtils.Copy(zipStream, s, buffer);
                files.Add(entryFileName, s);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                file.IsStreamOwner = true; // Makes close also shut the underlying stream
                file.Close(); // Ensure we release resources
            }
        }
        return files;
    }
```

even i try with this other code without result but now throw me a different error

> ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip.ZipException: 'Invalid password'

but the password is correct i can uncompress file using 7Zip or WinZip10

```
 public static Dictionary<string, MemoryStream> UnZip(MemoryStream stream, string password)
    {
        Dictionary<string, MemoryStream> files = new Dictionary<string, MemoryStream>();
        using (ZipInputStream zip = new ZipInputStream(stream))
        {
            zip.Password = password;
            //file.UseZip64 = UseZip64.On;

            //file.CommitUpdate();
            ZipEntry zipEntry;
            if ((zipEntry = zip.GetNextEntry()) != null)
            {
                string directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(zipEntry.Name);
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(zipEntry.Name);
                Console.WriteLine($"zipEntry directoryName={directoryName} fileName={fileName}");
                // create directory
                if (directoryName.Length > 0)
                {
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(directoryName);
                }
                if (fileName != String.Empty)
                {
                    MemoryStream streamWriter = new MemoryStream();
                    int size = 2048;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[2048];
                    while (true)
                    {
                        size = zip.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        if (size > 0)
                        {
                            streamWriter.Write(buffer, 0, size);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    files.Add(fileName, streamWriter);
                }
            }
        }
        return files;
    }
```

the zip file was created by a third so i can't change the version or the way that will created

Comment: Can you try to create a zip with a password and unzip with your code? Same exception or it works?

Comment: following your instructions i create two zip files using two encryptation methods, first with ZipCrypto and Second with AES-256, in first case ZipCrypto the code can uncompress files, but when i trey to uncompress AES-256 file the code throw me the same Exception, now i think that is a encryptation issue.

Comment: Probably is not supported, have you tried to look on the GitHub repo?

Comment: yes, i think the is probably not compatible. i try with a different library and now have a more specific error 

'Cannot extract: Entry 7449_MI_desact_A1.0920.txt is encrypted with an algorithm not supported by DotNetZip: PKWare AES128' so maybe SharpZipLib has problems with AES encryptions.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/issues/181)

Comment: I rebuild the dll with the proposed modifications but it still doesn't work